# Node Project & Practice

Tags: node.js

I am learning Node JS. It had almost learnt 70%. I am very interested in Backend Development but I'm not interested in Frontend development. My question is how do I practice my Node Skills. I only know HTML, CSS in Frontend. How can I make projects in Node JS without knowing Frontend? Or do I need to learn frontend frameworks such as React too to make projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can build an API and use postman to make requests. Start with something simple and keep improving by refactoring your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can work on the API creation part but in my opinion, you must learn one frontend framework it will not only increase your skill sets but also help you to coordinate with frontend easily and take more advantage of it than the projects you will build will be more useful and advanced as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could also focus on implementing some algorithms and data structures starting of with simple ones such as LinkedLists, ArrayLists, sorting algorithms and then move on to (binary) trees and graphs.
These will be required for any programming language to solve (complex) problems and there are many books and internet resources for this. Just search for `algorithms and data structures` and you'll get plenty. You don't need more than a console application with some simple `console.log()` statements to implement algorithms - no need for fancy UI.

Last but not least, you should certainly have a look at [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) if you want to develop more complex backend applications.

If you really want to do Web Development though it is certainly helpful to have a basic understanding of frontend development or know the basics of common frameworks such as [React](https://reactjs.org/), [Vue](https://vuejs.org/), [Angular](https://angular.io/) or [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/).
As others have mentioned for API development you could also just use [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) to send requests.